# Creating new column based on containing letter below

Tags: excel, excel-formula, character

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```html
Nickel  10
Nickel  U
Nickel  10
Nickel  U
Nickel  10
Nickel  U
Nickel  1.4
Nickel  J
Nickel  10
Nickel  U
Nickel  10
Nickel  U
Nickel  10
Nickel  U
Sodium  8.1
Sodium  7.4
Sodium  6.2
Sodium  7.6
Sodium  7.9
Sodium  6.9
Sodium  7.8
Sodium  8.9
Sodium  9
Sodium  7.9
Sodium  7
Sodium  R
Sodium  8.4
Sodium  7.7
```

Some rows have characters below it that correspond to the number above. Example: Nickel 10 U. I would like to add another column for the character IF a number has that character below it. The tricky part is, some are values do not correspond to a character (if there is not a character below) and those will need to remain blank.

Can I create a code that asks: if there is a character below a value, then add character in adjacent column. If there is no character below a value, leave the column adjacent blank.

Comment: `ISTEXT` might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(ISTEXT(B2),B2,"")
```

This checks the cell beneath in column B. If it is text then it returns the letter in the cell beneath. If it is not text then it returns blank. You can drag the formula down to cover all of your data.

[image: Screenshot of Excel solution using IF statement to check the cell beneath]

Answer (score 0):

### Shifting Data

**Single Cell (Copy Down)**

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B1),ISTEXT(B2)),B2,"")
```

**Array Formula (Spills in Microsoft 365)**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B1:B13)*ISTEXT(B2:B14),B2:B14,"")
```

[image]

**Nitpicking**

- Both solutions are actually inaccurate since they include the header (`B1`).
- Shifting the ranges one row down will similarly include a cell below the data (`B15`).
- In Microsoft 365, you can work around this by getting a version of the data shifted up by using `VSTACK` and `DROP`. Then you can compare the values side-by-side so to speak (see columns `E:F`).

```
=LET(d,B2:B14,
    s,VSTACK(DROP(d,1),""),
IF(ISNUMBER(d)*ISTEXT(s),s,""))
```